# Set datetime field now in MapStruct?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct, java.time.instant

I have an Instant field in my POJO class and want to set its value `now()` while creating record. As far as I see, MapStruct let this kind of feature, but I could not set it properly:

***mapper:***

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", imports = {Instant.class})
public interface CreatePostRequestMapper {

    // @Mapping(target = "createdAt", defaultExpression ="java(Instant.now())")
    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", defaultValue = "java(Instant.now())")
    Post toEntity(CreatePostRequest source);

    CreatePostRequest toDto(Post destination);
}
```

And both classes has the same property with the same name:

```
private Instant createdAt;
```

Here is the service method:

```
private final CreatePostRequestMapper createPostRequestMapper;

public PostDetails createPost(@Valid CreatePostRequest request) {
    final Post post = createPostRequestMapper.toEntity(request);

    // code omitted
}
```

This gives the following error:

"Request processing failed; nested exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'java(Instant.now())' could not be parsed at index 0] with root cause"

How can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **defaultValue** for Instant class, it will generate following code:

```
post.setCreatedAt( Instant.parse( "java(Instant.now())" ) );
```

And, obviously, Instant class cannot parse this string and create an object.

So, the right way is to use **defaultExpression**, this will generate following code:

```
post.setCreatedAt( Instant.now() );
```

The difference is noticeable :)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Very good. On the other hand, d you have an idea for setting Instant globally? This works for DateTime, but cannot implement it for Instant. Any idea -->

Comment: `@Configuration
public class AppConfig {  @Bean  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {     return builder -> {           builder.simpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT)));
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)));
            // not working >>>
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
        };
    }
}`

Comment: Do you mean, how to setup a configuration to serialize Instant field in a proper DATE_TIME_FORMAT string format?

Comment: In my Spring Boot project, I can format LocalDate and LocalDateTime with that global config. I also want to format my Instant field in DATE_TIME_FORMAT, but could not find a proper parameters (the serializer method takes different parameters):

Comment: Looked up in the library and I do not know why, but class InstantSerializer has only protected constructors. Currently, I can only recommend you manually add @JsonSerialize annotation to every Instant field